# Access class path property AND user-defined property file with Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-3

I have tried to access class path property & user-defined path property file as below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>Common.properties</value>
            <value>user.home:/database.properties</value>
        </list>
      </property> 
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Here `Common.properties` path is working but `user.home:/database.properties` path is not working. It is showing the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [user.home:/database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
(MSC service thread 1-6) at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
```

Am using jBoss 7 and I have changed standalone.bat to include the below path:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.home=file:%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%/database.properties
```

Is this correct?? If any other way to access custom property path please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using placeholders to hold the System property key: `${user.home}`. Also you have duplicated the `database.properties` in the System property and the config file.

Comment: How to create new System property and need to create new system property procedures?

Comment: ??? I think I might understand that question? To create a System property normally you set `-Dx=y` on the java command line. I see you are doing that through `JAVA_OPTS` and a script which is fine. Note, however, that `user.home` is reserved by the JVM and you might not be able to set that yourself (so better to use some key that you make up yourself, e.g. `config.home`).